# how to set the constraints for constrOptim

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a function that has needs weights to be applied to a matrix to return a scalar value. But the weights can only be between an upper and lower bound say `c(-5,5)`, and must sum to less than a numerical value `y`. How does one apply these contraints to the constrOptim function?

So for example my function could be any function that does the trick but im going to provide a mock example one anyway...(I think its non-linear...)

example weights are where `y==1` is say

```
weights <- c(0.1,0.4,0.5)

require(timeSeries)

objective.fun <- function(weights, matrix.obj){
    sum( colSds( matrix.obj * rep(weights,each=nrow(matrix.obj)) )
}
```

and an example matrix.obj of say

```
matrix.obj <- data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100)))
```

The number of columns is variable....

Comment: If your objective and constraints are linear like in your example, i.e., your problem is a Linear Programming (LP), then the simplex method will be a lot more efficient at solving your problem. You could use `Rlpk::Rglpk_solve_LP` for example.`

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I had made a mistake in my original example, and have edited it to make it closer to what I think is my actual problem. Would this still be linear?